PhpStorm reloading by itself
PhpStorm reloads itself periodically by closing all my tabs and folders. I'd like to describe my problem more, but I don't have any leads. I'm on the latest version of PhpStorm (Build #PS-241.18034.69, built on June 21, 2024) and on MacOS 14.5
My project is mounted on a docker container that I tried to stop (maybe some files were modified from it). I also tried reinstalling the IDE and rebooting the computer. I also ran the "Repair IDE" utility just in case.

"...by closing all my tabs and folders" Seems similar to what it would do if it is unable to read the file system (e.g. it will close the opened editor file if that file was deleted outside the IDE). The IDE needs a file to be present/reachable; it does not work with "in memory file" kind of buffers. No idea what might be causing it to do this "periodically" though, especially on Mac (on Windows I could think of antivirus interference or alike).

No other/better ideas from me expect use Help | Contact Support.... to make a support ticket with PhpStorm team where you can privately provide all required information / logs etc.

I removed the configuration directory (~/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PhpStorm2024.1). And restarted the IDE.
I still have no clue what the problem was exactly but at least it now works.
